# Non-Tiled Maps in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.6

I'm quite green in Pygame, but after stepping thorugh the tutorials and 
some playing with existing examples I think I should start up something. Since 
I'm a strategygamer I thought to give it a try. So..

To create a simple "Risk" like map to send my hordes of armies around on, what 
would you advice to be the best? Is there somekind of "clickable" graphic-file 
to use or should I simply draw rects in pygame and detect clicks on those?

Best regards,

Matias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use an image and utilize the color of the images to find out which country is being hovered/clicked.

```
if ev.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            # Get color underneath mouse cursor
            pos = ev.pos
            button = ev.button
            color = self.surface.get_at((pos))
```